# laravel4 hyperlink is not showing in yahoo,outlook but in gmail hyperlink is working

Tags: php, email, laravel-4

i am new in laravel4,i am developing a website and create an user registration functionality successfully.After a registration,the certain user will get an email for account activation,which is absolutely working fine in my web app.

**but the problem is , the verification code which should be appear as a hyperlink,not appearing as a hyperlink except Gmail,that is,in other email service provider like yahoo,outlook,GMX... that verification code is not appearing as hyperlink.. only appearing as a plain text.**

now here is my mail.php file

```
<?php

return array(

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mail Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
| sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
| your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
|
| Supported: "smtp", "mail", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "log"
|
*/

'driver' => 'smtp',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
| applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
| the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
|
*/

'host' => 'mail.forgroup.com',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Port
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
| users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
| stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
|
*/

'port' => 465,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global "From" Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
| the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
| used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
|
*/

'from' => array('address' => '******@*******.com', 'name' => '*******'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| E-Mail Encryption Protocol
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
| the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
| transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
|
*/

'encryption' => 'ssl',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Username
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
| set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
| connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
|
*/

'username' => '******',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Password
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may set the password required by your SMTP server to send out
| messages from your application. This will be given to the server on
| connection so that the application will be able to send messages.
|
*/

'password' => '*******',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Sendmail System Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
| the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
| been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
|
*/

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mail "Pretend"
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When this option is enabled, e-mail will not actually be sent over the
| web and will instead be written to your application's logs files so
| you may inspect the message. This is great for local development.
|
*/

'pretend' => false,

);
```

though i have no idea,whats the  reason for this error,i have tried to change the port in my mail.php file.Previously my port value was 465,after changing it to 25,i am getting the following error,so i have get back to my previous port which is 465

```
Swift_TransportException
Connection could not be established with host mail.foragroup.com [ #0]
```

after that i have tried the another encryption "tls" instead of "ssl",but after that i am facing the following error

```
Swift_TransportException
Connection to tcp://mail.forgroup.com:465 Timed Out
```

now though i have no clear idea,i am giving you my controller by which actually i am sending the verification mail,here is the controller

```
public function signupPost()
{
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(

        'email'             => 'required|max:255|email|unique:users',
        'username'          => 'required|min:4|unique:users',
        'password'          => 'required|min:8',
        'password_again'    =>  'required|same:password'

        )
    );

    if($validator->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::route('signup')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }else
    {
        $email          = Input::get('email');
        $username       = Input::get('username');
        $password       = Input::get('password');

        //Activation Code
        $code = str_random(60);

        $user = User::create(array(
                    'email'     => $email,
                    'username'  => $username,
                    'password'  => Hash::make($password),
                    'code'      => $code,
                    'active'    => 0                
                    )
        );

        if($user){
            //User Activation Code Creation
            Mail::send('emails.auth.activate', array('link' => URL::route('activate-account',$code), 'username' => $username),function($message) use ($user)
                {
                    $message->to($user->email,$user->username)->subject('Activate Your Account');
                });

            return Redirect::route('signup')
                            ->with('global','Your Account has been created! We have sent you an email to activate your account.Please Check the both the Inbox and Spam Folder.');

        }

    }



}
```

**UPDATE**

This is the my activate HTML file

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Hello <strong><h1 style="color:#1B438D">{{$username}}</h1></strong></h3> <br><br>
    Please Activate Your Account Using The Following Link <br><br>

<b>NOTE</b><h3 style="color:red;">If the following code is not a link or clickable,then please              <b>COPY</b><br/>
the whole code and <b>PASTE</b> it in NEW TAB of your browser.</h3> 


----
{{$link}}
----

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your result email content type text/plain or text/html?

Comment: do you talking about the html file which actually containing the message or body of the email?

Comment: Do u still have this issue ?

Comment: can you help me with this issue @evoque2015

Comment: I believed the error is in the view of email/auth/activate.
How do you style your activate button ? 
Can you update that on your post ? Throw in that view for me, so I can help you take a look. It's an easy fix - don't worry

Answer (score 0):

According to your situation, I don't think that the error is in `mail.php`, otherwise, you won't be able to sent out any email.

I suspect the error is in `email/auth/activate.blade.php`

Compare mine with your and note the diff.

Here is how I style my activation button, and it's work across all the email clients. 
I've already tested with Google, Outlook, and more.

```
<div style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #90bc26; font-size: 13px;">
      <a target="_blank" href="http://{{ str_replace("http://","",$link); }}" style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; margin: 0px; text-align: center; vertical-align: baseline; border: 4px solid #90bc26; padding: 4px 9px; font-size: 15px; line-height: 21px; background-color: #90bc26;">&nbsp; Activate Now &nbsp;</a>
    </div>
```

Replace your activate button with mine, and let me know how it go ...

I remembered when I came across that problem.

Comment: I am sorry,its not working in live server,but in local server the activation link is appearing as hyperlink(in yahoo,gmail),but after clicking the link,a pop up windows appears and warns that "the link containing wrong format of web address", but my concern is it still not working in the live server,i am in fact using Cpanel.

Comment: Rego, Edit your post, and show your exact error. Take a screenshot if you can. I'll help u debug this.

Comment: evoque2015 , i have updated my post,in mention ,according to your  answer,in my local server everything seems fine,but in live server nothing has been changed.I have given my activate html above.If you need any further code,then please ask me.

Comment: My above given Activate HTML file is the old one.But after changing the link button according to your answer,it seems that its working in the every email service provider.But i have tried using Yahoo,there after clicking in the hyperlink,a pop windows warns me that the website address format is non-standard.